# Magento1.9.2.4 Js not loading

Tags: javascript, magento

Js not loading when products in [Home page](http://dev.ornativa.in/) "New Born" section and "I am Best" section are clicked. Also the entire page does not load properly, **Add to cart** button is not working and I am not able to scroll to the "Product Details" section,

The Google chrome console is giving the following error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined
    
at addCartOnDetail (ajaxcart.js:3)
    
at initAjaxcart (ajaxcart.js:3)
    
at HTMLDocument. (ajaxcart.js:3)
    
at o (jquery.min.js:2)
    
at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
    
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    
at HTMLDocument.B (jquery.min.js:2)

Reference Link:

1. http://dev.ornativa.in/black-rose-stud

But if I open the same product from **Earrings** category everything is working properly.

Even if I posting the link in the social media then also the same problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally delete this part of code from view.phtml?

```
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
```

This script is inserted at the bottom of the every view.phtml under catalog/product template folders.

Please check out those paths.